# treating potato plant disease with ridomil

Tags: diseases, potatoes

Potatoes in our garden got attacked by a disease. Take a look:

[image]

[image]

Presumably, this is late blight. The recommended practice is to spray potatoes with ridomil fungicide. I am very skeptical about using it. Do you think this is the way to go? Are there alternatives? Potatoes were planted 50 days ago. I live is south central Europe.

PS: I've put freshly mowed grass in between some rows as a cover. Is this the reason for diseases eruption?

Also, the garden is tight packed with plants and the lettuce is just a few meters away from the potatoes which makes me want to use fungicide even less.